# Python Flask - How to set a default value of NULL for type Date in a form

Tags: python, datetime, flask, null, nonetype

I have an HTML form to update field values. Within this form, I have a field called `app_deadlines`, which is of type Date:

`my_data.app_deadlines = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form['app_deadlines'], "%Y-%m-%d")`

If I leave that field empty and press the submit button to update, it throws the error shown below.

```
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

^^Therefore, the database update doesn't occur.

In essence, it won't leave the attribute as NULL (which is how it's stored in my SQLite database table) when I update, so how do I set it so that it accepts NULL? It won't let me do `or None`, which worked for another field:

`my_data.cfda_no = request.form['cfda_no'] or None`

What could the default NULL value for type Date be so that it's still stored in the format '%Y-%m-%d'?

Class View:

```
class FundingSource(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    complete = db.Column(db.String(10), default=False, nullable=False)
    department = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    agency = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    cfda_no = db.Column(db.Float(), nullable=True)
    app_deadlines = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=True)
```

Flask View:

```
@main.route("/update", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_data = FundingSource.query.get(request.form.get('id'))

        my_data.complete = request.form['complete']
        my_data.department = request.form['department']
        my_data.agency = request.form['agency']
        my_data.cfda_no = request.form['cfda_no'] or None
        my_data.app_deadlines = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form['app_deadlines'], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting an error when no date is provided, so you want to be able to handle receiving both date and None values. Because **datetime.datetime.strptime()** only accepts date values, you can add a logic check to handle None values by using an inline statement:

```
my_data.expiration_funds = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form['expiration_funds'], '%Y-%m-%d') if request.form['expiration_funds'] else None
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!